# Positive scalar curvature and $\mathbf{H}P^2$-bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cobordism, curvature

Let $M$ be a simply-connected spin-manifold of dimension $n\geq 5$. The Atiyah-Bott-Shapiro orientation $\mathrm{MSpin} \to KO$ produces an element $\alpha(M)$ of $\pi_n KO$. Results of Gromov-Lawson and Stolz imply that $M$ has a metric of positive scalar curvature if and only if $\alpha(M) = 0$. Further, Kreck and Stolz have shown that the kernel of the map $\pi_\ast \mathrm{MSpin} \to \pi_\ast KO$ from the spin cobordism ring to the KO-theory of a point is precisely the ideal consisting of cobordism classes of total spaces of $\mathbf{H}P^2$-bundles. In particular, this implies that a simply-connected spin-manifold of dimension $\geq 5$ admits a metric of positive scalar curvature if and only if it is cobordant to the total space of an $\mathbf{H}P^2$-bundle.

This is a statement that relates two geometric conditions on a manifold, so I was wondering if it's possible to give a purely geometric proof. In particular, can one prove the final statement of the last paragraph without relying on the Atiyah-Bott-Shapiro orientation?

If a manifold is the total space of an $\mathbf{H}P^2$-bundle, it has a metric of positive scalar curvature; this is a consequence of the fact that $\mathbf{H}P^2$ admits a metric of positive scalar curvature. The other direction is the more nontrivial one which I don't know how to approach.